# PHP Failed to update database

Tags: php, mysql

it's my first time working with php and after 2h of searching for my problem i came to the conclusion that i cant find and fix it.

I hope you guys can help me!

```
 <?php

require "./config/_sqlconnect.php";

$temp = $_POST;
$vname = "Peter";
$nname = "Hans";
$straße ="XY";
$strnr ="8";
$plz = "9031";
$ort = "würzburg";
$land ="deutschland";
$tel ="1334134";
$email ="asdas@aasd.com";
$datum ="21.03.1942";
$anrede ="herr";

$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die
("Verbindungsversuch fehlgeschlagen");

mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die('DB FAIL');

$sql = "INSERT INTO tadresse (vname,nname,straße,strnr,plz,ort,land,tel,email,datum,anrede) VALUES($temp)";

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO tadresse (vname,nname,straße,strnr,plz,ort,land,tel,email,datum,anrede) VALUES ('$vname','$nname','$straße','$strnr','$plz','$ort','$land','$tel','$email','$datum','$anrede')";
    $eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);

    if($eintragen == true)
        {
            echo 'RICHTIG';
        }
    else
        {
            echo 'FEHLER';
    }?>
```

the Result:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\aufgabe\text.php on line 23
FEHLER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggest you are passing an `array`, but there is needed of a `string`. Your `$temp` is an array because it's the same as `$_POST`. So if you are sure that you want to pass there the `$temp` you have to change like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tadresse (vname,nname,straße,strnr,plz,ort,land,tel,email,datum,anrede) VALUES('" . implode("','", $temp) . "')";
```

But I see that you also have all the variables also so you can pass one by one here in VALUES like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tadresse (vname,nname,straße,strnr,plz,ort,land,tel,email,datum,anrede) VALUES('$vname', '$nname', '$straße', ....)";
```

And my suggestion is to use only English characters so to change  `$straße` to something else

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem with the array to string conversion! 
I still have the problem, that my 

$eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);

is not true. I was about to change it :)

Comment: And also `mysql_query` is deprecated so you should use something else. You can use `PDO` or `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Also using directly user-given data without validaton / sanitization is wayyyyyy too unsafe to be overlooked.